# Compare dates on moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am working with the library moment.js to get the difference in months between two dates .. the code works fine .. however this only takes a month when they are the same day eg: first date = 2017-08-14, second Date = 2017-09-14 ... only in this case takes into account the full month, now my question is ahy some way that if the second date was: 2017-09-12 for example .. I already take into account like a month?

I leave the little code I have.

```js
var date1 = moment('2017-08-14');
var date2 = moment('2017-09-12');
var result = date2.diff(date1, 'months');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to specify the format here.  Otherwise how does moment know whether it is YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-DD-MM?

Comment: @axlj If not specified I think momentjs falls back to the [ISO 8601 standard](https://momentjs.com/docs/#supported-iso-8601-strings), which is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) `.diff()` will round down when the value is positive, and round up when the value is negative (i.e. positive values < 1 will be rounded down to 0):

> By default, moment#diff will return a number rounded towards zero (down for positive, up for negative). If you want a floating point number, pass true as the third argument.

If you want a floating point number, simply do this:

```
var result = date2.diff(date1, 'months', true);
```

And you can apply your own rounding up/down preference. If you want to round to the nearest month, use:

```
var result = Math.round(date2.diff(date1, 'months', true));
```

```js
var date1 = moment('2017-08-14');
var date2 = moment('2017-09-12');
var result = date2.diff(date1, 'months', true);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

On a related note, if you want to detect if **a month boundary has been crossed between two dates** (e.g. you want 31st August 2017 vs 1st September 2017 to be counted as one month difference because the month changes from august to september), you can simply extract the month from the dates using [`.month()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and calculate the difference yourself:

```js
var date1 = moment('2017-08-31');
var date2 = moment('2017-09-01');
var result = date2.month() - date1.month();
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```